# Recursive macro call in twig template

Tags: twig

After I upgraded my Silex installation to Version 2.x, the macros that I wrote previously do not work.

```
{% macro render_map(data) %}
    /**
     * Do some stuff
    */
   {{ __self.render_map(argument) }} 
{% endmacro %}
```

After some research I find that the "__self" operator was deprecated and I tried this solution:

```
{% import _self as macros %}
{% macro render_map(data) %}
   /**
    * Do some stuff
   */
  {{ macros.render_map(argument) }}
{% endmacro %}
```

Has anyone a solution for my issue?

Comment: "do not work" is not a problem description. Why not? What happened instead? "and I tried this solution:" And? Why didn't that work either?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/macro.html):

> When you want to use a macro in another macro from the same file, you
>   need to import it locally: ...

So:

```
{% macro render_map(data) %}
  {% import _self as macros %}

  // ...

  {{ macros.render_map(argument) }}
{% endmacro %}
```

Demo: https://twigfiddle.com/jtfo4h

Comment: Ok, this was mistake. After I write the import statement after the macro statement it works :) Many thanks for your help